# ROS for Ubuntu Release: 17.10/artful?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would someone here know what the plans for a release of ROS for Ubuntu 17.10?  I have to be on 17.10 but I am not finding any compiled package for that on the Internet.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282619/ros-for-ubuntu-release:-17.10/artful?/) by [Shankar Swamy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33697/shankar-swamy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Related question: #q277021 (provides a work-around with Docker).

**Comment by [Shankar Swamy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33697/shankar-swamy/) on 2018-02-14**:
Good to know; but unfortunately that is not a good option for me as I am on VirtualBox and Docker and VirtualBox at times don't get along very well. :-(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
The idea was to use the `Dockerfile` only as a *recipe*. It shows the exact steps that would let you build Lunar on an Ubuntu Artful installation from source. Using it as a Docker container is possible, but not at all needed.

(you probably know this already, but ROS (RViz) in a VM can be difficult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic) will support Ubuntu 17.10 once it's released.

[REP-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023) is the place where supported platforms and libraries are specified.

Note that the support for non-LTS Ubuntu distros like 17.10 will be terminated when the corresponding support for Ubuntu reaches EOL (end-of-life) (e.g. [announcement of ROS Lunar ending supporting Ubuntu 17.04](https://discourse.ros.org/t/suspension-of-debian-packaging-for-eol-ubuntu-zesty-17-04/3742)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1